# What is name for the effect of Mac OS's file panels expanded view?

Tags: macos, reactjs, filesystems, panel

Been trying to find similar component, have not yet find one. I want a component that basically able to expand an object to a panel next to it just like MacOS's file system. I wonder if anyone already know such exist and found it? Since I have no idea what this effect's name to start search from .
I am trying specifically, looking for a reactjs / pure js based visual component does it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of view is known as [Miller columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns).

Comment: wonder how did you ever find this name or you just knew it from someone else? @duskwuff
I can't imagine how did you do the research with this lol

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `NSBrowser`.

It's kind of deprecated (Apple has never updated it to use views, so you still have to use cells). It's also idiosyncratic and has lots of undocumented behavior.

Enjoy ;)